# Cordova Android project fails compile with duplicate google/gms

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins

A previously good cordova app is now failing compile with the following error and variations (always duplicate entries of com/google/android/gms/ ... something...)

```
    :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease FAILED

     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

     * What went wrong: Execution failed for task 
 ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.
  ZipException: duplicate entry:
     com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/Container$FunctionCallMacroCallback.class
```

I've looked at many many other cases here at Stackoverflow of similar errors, and applied solutions that have worked for others:

- I've installed the plugin "cordova-android-support-gradle-release 2.0.1" and set it to match the android support v4 version:

> ```
> <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.1">
>     <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="24.1.1" />
> ```

- I've examined the app and android build.gradle files for duplicate compiles of google services. There's only one:

> ```
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
>     // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
>     implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
>     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"
>     compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
>     // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
> }
> ```

- I've run Cordova Clean
- I've removed the android platform and reinstalled
- I've compiled with the cordova command line build
- I've synched and compiled with the latest Android Studio version
- I've synched and compiled with the last Android Studio version that it compiled under, preview 3.2
- I've added the following to the app's build.gradle defaultConfig block:

> ```
>     minSdkVersion 19
>     targetSdkVersion 28
>     multiDexEnabled true
> ```

- I've updated all my plugins:

> ```
> cordova-launch-review 2.0.2 "Launch Review"
> cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
> cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
> cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.4 "Notification"
> cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
> cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
> cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.6 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
> cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.3 "Google Play Services for Android"
> cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
> cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3-dev "Splashscreen"
> cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
> cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
> cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.4 "SocialSharing"
> es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
> ```

- I've downloaded and installed the support repository

What in the name of Ada Lovelace am I missing??????

UPDATE EDIT:

I ran ./gradlew :app:dependencies from the /platforms/android directory and got this:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 24.1.1
|    |    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+ -> 24.1.1 (*)
\--- project :CordovaLib
```

The only library in my /platforms/android/app/libs directory is:
google-play-services.jar

Comment: Do you have a **rogue** library (unwanted/there by mistake) in your `libs` directory (take a look)? Try **`./gradlew :app:dependencies`** to see what might be conflicting (duplicates).

Comment: cool @brianfit I'll take a look when I've not been awake for 24 hours ;O) your in safe hands....

Comment: Thanks Jon so much, I don't know how I missed that command. I put the output into the question as an update edit. Honestly, I don't know how to parse that to tell what's valid and what's not -- I see mulitple references to play-services-basement, e.g. but as sub-branches of non-duplicate entries.

Comment: ADA rocks ! (most {by a long way} of the first programmers were women)

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be a known incompatibility between Dan Wilson's Google Analytics plugin for cordova and Android

> Important Note If the latest versions (0.8.0+) of this plugin are not
>   working for you with Android on Cordova 5.0+, please try the
>   suggestions in [Issues 123](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/123#issuecomment-151145095). Google Play Services has been very
>   confusing to integrate, but in recent months it has been simplified.
>   This plugin uses the new simpler way (including it as a framework
>   instead of bundling it which can conflict with other plugins bundling
>   it), but if you previously installed this plugin some old files might
>   still be lingering.

The fix, [as outlined here](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/123#issuecomment-151145095),  was to install the Android Support Repository, as I'd already done, and update Google Play Service and Google Repository, which I'd already done, and:

**delete the google services jar from /platforms/android/app/libs**

That solved it. @Jon-Goodwin I restored the line

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
```

to the /platforms/android/app/project.properties file and it successfully compiled, so removing the jar file seems to have removed the conflict. The app appeared to compile and run with and without it, provided the google-play-services.jar file was gone from /platforms/android/app/libs.